# Defining Invalid Paths on a Graph

Tags: data-structures, graph-algorithm

We are working on a project that a regular directed graph is suitable for most cases. However on our graph we want to invalidate some paths. For example if our graph is:

```
A->B
A->D
B->C
D->C
```

Then A->B->C is a valid path but A->D->C is not. We could define invalid paths somewhere and do a validation check every time but this cause an important performance issue since our application highly depends on the graph.

So, is there a special data structure or algorithm for this type situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could store a mapping at each node of `from:list(to)` so you know that a path coming from A can not go to C because it isn't in the list of nodes it can go to from C. If you ahve a depth greater than 1, the tuple of nodes leading up to it can be a key instead of that one node. This is a lot like how eBGP works for internet routing.

On a different note, you will need to do a check no matter what if you decide to use a data structure like you're describing. Either that, or store multiple graphs for each situation.